L1 Cache hit 0% for matrix multiplications
Doing large matrix multiplication operation on a GPU. The kernel profiling shows the L1 cache hit as 0%.The matrix stride is over 4k bytes and cache line size is 128 bytes. What could be the possible reasons for this L1 cache hit?
Thanks

Well, you haven't given us much information to go by, so let's discuss this in principle:
Neither loads, nor stores, in CUDA have to update the L1 cache. There are kinds of load or store instructions, or caching policy specifiers for load or store instructions, which may avoid it.
Specifically,

The compiler is likely to prefer loads through __restrict'ed pointers to const data via non-coherent read-only cache; see this answer here on SO, or the CUDA. This corresponds to the ld.global.nc PTX instruction; you might also see this done using the CUDA C++ __ldg() instrinsic.
Under some circumstances, the compiler will emit store instructions with the .cg (cache-global) or .wt (write-through ) cache modifiers, both of which will skip writing to the L1 level. See the PTX store instruction caching preference option table.

when both of these happen, the L1 cache hit rate should indeed be 0%. If you're only looking at cache hits during read, then just the first bullet might be enough to result in 0% cache hit rate.

Thank you @einpoklum, this is exactly what the issue was. Regards

@Jarvis: The way to thank someone on StackOverflow is to upvote their answer... also, if an answer is the correct solution, you accept it. This is done using the controls around the number next to the top of the answer... welcome to StackOverflow :-)
